# strftime returns me empty string

Tags: php, timestamp, strftime

I have a really simple error and I don't get why **stftime PHP function** returns me an **empty string** while all seems right with the syntax and code.

*I got the following code:*

```php
$next_high_tide_date = strtotime($next_high_tide_date);
// FROM '2021-05-22 00:26:00' TO (timestamp) 1621635960
$next_high_tide_date_day = strtoupper(strftime('%A %d %B', $next_high_tide_date));
// THIS RETURNS ME THE RIGHT DAY DATE
$next_high_tide_date_hour = strtoupper(strftime('%k H %M', $next_high_tide_date));
// THIS RETURNS ME AN EMPTY STRING
```

My `$next_hight_tide_date` value after the first declaration is equal to `1621643160` (timestamp).
I checked on a [strftime checker online](https://fr.functions-online.com/strftime.html) and my code is right, but in my php page, still returns me a empty string.

Anyone has an idea ?

[image: capture of my code]

Comment: What is the value of `$next_high_tide_date` that you're testing on (the original one)?

Comment: I test with the timestamp I precised in my post : `1621643160`

Comment: Sorry, yeah, I've realized I wasn't precise and edited the comment.

Comment: Currently this is a string `2021-05-22 00:26:00`. It can change due to API value but it's always this form.

Comment: Anyway, with the timestamp I get results `SATURDAY 22 MAY` and `2 H 26`. See [here](https://3v4l.org/X4BMb).

Comment: With the string I also get an [expected result](https://3v4l.org/fehTa). Your problem must be elsewhere. Where and how are you checking/displaying these values?

Comment: I'm displaying this value with `var_dump()`, and when I display this right after my `$next_high_tide_date_hour` declaration, it gives me an **empty string**. I forgot to say that `$next_high_tide_date_hour` return me **empty string** and `$next_high_tide_date_day` returns me the **expected result**. So I really don't understand.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://ideone.com/4J4wi8 Something you didn't show must be changing `$next_high_tide_date` between the two calls to `strftime()`

Comment: Well, the code in your question works (as demonstrated by both Barmar and myself), so you'd have to post a reproducible problem.

Comment: Yes I don't understand aswell what is fucking up my code, I have nothing between my 2 strftime I swear. I'm getting my `$next_high_tide_date` from an API that has the `2021-05-22 00:26:00` value and I have nothing linked to these value in my php page after... I know this is weird.

Comment: I added a screen shot of my code

Comment: Since none of the variables that you check inside the `isset` are set in this script, I assume you are including this file somewhere else where they exist. If so, can you test this script by calling it directly, with hardcoded values?

Comment: So let me get this straight: you expect `strtoupper(strftime('%k H %M', 1621635960));` to return `0 H 26` but it returns `''` instead.

In the docs they give a warning about the C library not supporting all conversion specifiers. Don't know how you would go about debugging that, but it's a lead you could follow.

Based on the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php): %k is a valid format. Did you try setting the locale differently? In the docs I see someone doing: `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR.utf8','fra');`. And did you try other locales? Hope this helps you.

Comment: @CoenCoppens Thanks man, I don't know where you saw that exactly but it was probably a compatibilty support. %k isn't working while %H is. Dumb from me to not test another format earlier. Changing locale didn't changed anything by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use the `date()` function to format your timestamp.

```
$next_high_tide_date = "2021-05-22 00:26:00";
$next_high_tide_date = strtotime($next_high_tide_date);
$next_high_tide_date_day = strtoupper(date('l d F', $next_high_tide_date));
$next_high_tide_date_hour = strtoupper(date('H \H i', $next_high_tide_date));
```

try this

or use `%H` instead of `%k`

```
$next_high_tide_date = "2021-05-22 00:26:00";
$next_high_tide_date = strtotime($next_high_tide_date);
$next_high_tide_date_day = strtoupper(strftime('%A %d %B',$next_high_tide_date));
$next_high_tide_date_hour = strtoupper(strftime('%H H %M',$next_high_tide_date));
```

Comment: yes strtotime() expects a string. And I give it a string. And then I  give the date to my strftime().

By the way date format are not like strftime format so this doesn't work anyway. And I choose strftime instead of date for a reason

Comment: @Kiji_T It's confusing because you use the same variable for the argument and result.

Comment: True. I could change it for the example.

Comment: The `date()` function doesn't use `%` before the formats.

Comment: Why do you think `date()` would be any more successful than `strftime()`? They're essentially the same, they just use different styles of format strings.

Comment: I don't know why but with an experimented eye that might give the response, but I use strftime to be able to change local language, so my date is in the expected language. And this works well with date. Is there anything the `setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_FR", "French");` could confuse my date ?

Comment: @Barmar because it works unlike `strftime`

Comment: @Kiji_T Maybe you can tell me for what reason you are using `strftime()` instead of `date()`

Comment: I think it is because you can't use `setlocale();` to change day language on `date()` function if I remember well.

Comment: @Kiji_T I added `setlocale()` to my ideone snippet, it still works correctly.

Comment: @Barmar yes... I don't know why it doesn't work. My code screenshot don't give you an idea of the problem it could be ?

Comment: @Kiji_T But it doesn't produce French date.

Comment: I guess my php is broken x)

Comment: @Kiji_T It works if you use the `%H` format instead of `%k` the only difference is the space before a single digit